# Database backup

Tags: 16.04, mysql, lamp, xampp, database

I want to take backup of Xampp database available in /opt/lampp/var/mysql
`but I am unable to do it.
I used below command

> /opt/lampp/htdocs/vivek.s$ sudo mysqldump -u root -p vive.se > 
>   07feb.sql

and

> /opt/lampp/htdocs/vivek.s$ sudo mysqldump -h root -u root -p vive.se >
>   07feb.sql

Result is same

> bash: 07feb.sql: Permission denied

Then I used

> sudo -s
>
> sudo mysqldump -u root -p vive.se > 07feb.sql

Result is

> sudo: mysqldump: command not found

and it created a Empty file named **07feb.sql** in **/opt/lampp/htdocs/vivek.s**

What is wrong while I saw my friend using same command and he got 
database backup of 95 MB.
What should I try.

Thanks

Comment: use a directory where you can store a file. the ">" part has no permission to write. Regarding the 2nd one: directory to mysqldump is not in the PATH. Use an absolute path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you do not have permission to write to `/opt/lampp/htdocs/vivek.s` as your normal user. Running `mysqldump` as root elevates mysqldump (unnecessarily), but the redirection happens with the permissions of the **shell** - running as your regular user.

There's a few workarounds:

1. Start a root shell by e.g. `sudo -i` or `sudo -s`. You should not use sudo to run the next command - mysqldump.
2. Use `tee`:

   mysqldump -u root -p vive.se | sudo tee 07feb.sql > /dev/null

This will run the process `tee` as root, writing one copy to file, and redirecting stdout to `/dev/null` as we don't need it.

Another workaround would be to write the backup to a location where your user has write permission, for instance your home directory.